# Psycopg / asyncio set even loop policy

Tags: python, python-asyncio, psycopg2, fastapi, uvicorn

Hope you're well!

I have a problem with the [Psycopg](https://pypi.org/project/psycopg/) module allowing to interact with the PostgreSQL database.

When I start my HTTP server (I use [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/) and [Uvicorn](https://www.uvicorn.org/)) normally, and I send a request to my server, I have this error:

```
error connecting in 'pool-1': Psycopg cannot use the 'ProactorEventLoop' to run in async mode. Please use a compatible event loop, for instance by setting 'asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())'
```

I have already done what the error solution suggests, that is, set the event loop policy to WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy, which I did.

```
import asyncio
from asyncio import WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy


asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```

I put this line in my main file (which is the central file of my app)
But still nothing, I still have the same error when I send a request to my server.

But what is strange is that when I start my server with the `--reload` option (which is used to [reload](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/#run-it) the files automatically in case of modification but is not adapted for production, according to the documentation of Uvicorn/FastAPI), I have no error when I send my requests and everything goes correctly

Can you tell me what is the cause of the problem and how to solve it?

P.S: Here is how i start my HTTP from Windows Powershell

Here is how I start my HTTP server normally (which doesn't works)

```
uvicorn src.main:app --port 2314
```

Here is how I start my HTTP server with the --reload option (which works perfectly)

```
uvicorn src.main:app --port 2314 --reload
```

Answer (score 2):

Uvicorn sets the `WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy` policy when using the `reload` option and Windows by default, otherwise it doesn't. That's why you are facing this mismatch behavior.

Changing another policy should have worked, maybe it's misplaced.

The below works:

```py
import asyncio
import uvicorn

asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.DefaultEventLoopPolicy())

async def app(scope, receive, send):
    print(asyncio.get_event_loop_policy())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run("main:app", port=8010)
```

If we remove the line on which we set the policy, and we have `uvloop` installed (`uvicorn` automatically selects `uvloop` if installed), we can see that the `uvloop` policy is printed.

In case it's not misplaced, I recommend open a discussion on `uvicorn`.

Disclaimer: I'm a maintainer of Uvicorn.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But why when I manually set the event loop policy to **WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy**, it doesn't take effect?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you're running asyncpg before the policy is changed.

Comment: the line **asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())** it's the first line right after all the imports

Comment: i tried to install **uvloop** . But i get this error while installing **RuntimeError('uvloop does not support Windows at the moment')**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! After having made several tests and having read again the documentation of uvicorn.

Everything was a little bit my fault

I launched the uvicorn HTTP server (without the `--reload` option) directly from the command line from a terminal (in my case Powershell), I got the error.

```
error connecting in 'pool-1': Psycopg cannot use the 'ProactorEventLoop' to run in async mode. Please use a compatible event loop, for instance by setting 'asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())'
```

Because this way of doing things didn't read the import I had done in my main.py file, but simply started the server without caring about anything, hence the error asking me to set the event loop policy to **WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy** (which I had done), simply because the import line defining my event loop policy was never reached.

So now instead of launching my uvicorn server directly in the terminal like this

```
uvicorn src.main:app --port 2314
```

I execute my python code like this

```
python -m src.main
```

and I had to modify my code in main.py like this

```
import asyncio
from asyncio import WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
...

asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())


app = FastAPI()

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run('src.main:app', host="127.0.0.1", port=2314)
```

The reason why it was working without any problem in the terminal is by running my HTTP server with the `--reload` option like this

```
uvicorn src.main:app --port 2314 --reload
```

is that as **@marcelo-trylesinski** said, the `--reload` option automatically sets event loop to **WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy**. I wish this could be notified / mentioned in the documentation.

Thanks again to **@marcelo-trylesinski** for his help

Comment: Hmmm... I tried the snippet I've pasted with the "CLI way", and I was able to change the policy.

In any case... PRs to improve documentation are always welcome. :)